# How do I append/add to a rosbag file without overwriting it in Python?

Tags: python, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically I was testing recording data to a rosbag using a timestamp.

I noticed that every time I open and close the file it just rewrites the data, so I just leave the file open when the program starts and close it when it ends.  However if I want to write to that same file it just overwrites all of the data.

How can I just append/add onto the same bag file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234730/how-do-i-append/add-to-a-rosbag-file-without-overwriting-it-in-python?/) by [newbsaibot](https://answers.ros.org/users/26923/newbsaibot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai krishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/29950/sai-krishna/) on 2019-03-14**:
I use rosbag to open a new bag file in append mode and it throws an ROSBagException : empty file any inputs how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think the rosbag file format or the API supports appending to a file.

Instead, the rosbag API supports seamlessly opening and reading from multiple bag files, so if I have multiple logging sessions, I record one bag file during each and then open all of them together when I want to analyze the data.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0